# Python: How to rename public available variable?

Tags: python, class, variables, rename

Imagine having this class:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nr = 0
```

Imagine further `Foo` being widely used. Several scripts and users use the variable `Foo.nr` to read and write its value.

Now suppose the developer wants to change the name of `.nr` to `.val`.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0
```

In order to not force the users to update their code, is it somehow possible to make them access `.val` by writing `.nr`? Like this:

```
f1 = Foo()
print(f1.nr)
```

I came up with properties and getter and setter methods but I don't see how they might help.

Comment: maybe adding a  `@property` with a setter and getter is a solution for this. Those can indeed just access the same `self.val`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0

    @property
    def nr(self):
        return self.val

    @nr.setter
    def nr(self, value):
        self.val = value
        
f1 = Foo()
print(f1.nr)
```

would give `0` as expected.

Comment: Goodness me, this was easy. Thank you.